# while loop don't work javascript

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I need help with this while loop

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     var num = window.prompt("enter score");
     var s, a;
     var count=0;
     while (num > 0) {
         s += num;
         count++;
     }
     a = s / count;
     document.write(a); </script>
```

why this loop doesn't work even when i put number higher than 0?

Comment: You should learn debugging your code. Examine it row by row while running it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Your problem can be easily found if you comment your code and go through every part, step by step.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     //Declare a variable of the users choice
     var num = window.prompt("enter score");
     //Declare counters
     var s, a;
     //Declare variable for holding number of times the loop has run
     var count=0;
     //Loop forever if num is greater than 0, since it is never changed
     while (num > 0) {
         //Add n to s. (Where does n come from? - not defined) S is never initialized
         s += n;
         //Add one to count
         count++
     }
     //Set a to be s / count
     a = s / count;
     //Write a to the document body
     document.write(a);
</script>
```

Document.write will write over what is currently in the document body - effectivly removing your code. Do not ever use document.write() if you don't know what you're doing.

You should also try to rewrite your code, since most of the lines could be removed by optimizing it further.

**EDIT:**

Op edited the code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     //Define and initialize a value input by the user
     var num = window.prompt("enter score")
     //Define sum (Not initialized) should be "var sum = 0;"
     var sum;
     //Define and initialize count
     var count=0;
     //For as long as num is larger than 0 (loop forever if num is bigger than 0)
     while (num > 0){
          //Add num to sum
          sum += num;
          //Add one to count
          count++;
     }
</script>
```

I would suggest you to learn javascript further and go through your code line by line as I've done above.

Comment: thanks but i still don't understand where is the problem, i changed the n and deleted everything after the while to check again but the loop stops after one time

Comment: I'm throwing together a testpage, one moment.

Comment: Javascript is a quite fragile language which can be hard to debug at times. I found a missing semicolon after window.prompt() and count++ and edited it. Try it again now.

Comment: I already changed it and it still stops after one time.
it happened to me here too:
http://puu.sh/cGN1n/a3c1ce0ea6.png
the code above doesn't work and the one under it works

Comment: You still have the problem with document.write(). Try console.log() for debuging instead.

Comment: even without document.write() there is still problem.

Comment: http://puu.sh/cGO0H/1bc2823e97.png
it works now 
i had to add : num = parseInt(window.prompt("enter score"));
in the loop

Answer (score 0):

The n term in the while loop does not look previously defined so that could be one issue, as well while(num > 0) stops looping when num becomes less than 0, but the value for num is not getting changed so it will never stop looping.

if you wanted the loop to count to score you could write

```
while(count < num){
   s += n;
   count++;
}
```

hope this helps,

cheers